# Is there a way to describe type for Proxy based on modified properties in typescript

Tags: typescript, es6-proxy

I have a list of routes:

```js
export interface RouteMap {
  routeA: string;
  routeB: string;
  routeC: string;
  ...
}

const routesMap: RouteMap = {
  routeA: 'route-a-url',
  routeB: 'route-b-url/:param',
  routeC: 'route-c-url/:some-id/data',
  
  ...
}
```

and a `Proxy` to object that could handle methods:

- get**RouteName**Url(...arg: any[]): string;
- goTo**RouteName**Url(...arg: any[]): void;
- probably some other dynamic boilerplate stuff

i.e. getRouteAUrl, getRouteBUrl and so on.

the question is:

> Is there a way to describe the Proxed object, that is based on some interface/class type's **modified** properties in typescript?

something like this

```js
type ProxedRouteMap<T> = {
  [get`[P in keyof T]`Url]: (...arg: string[]) => string;
  [goTo`[P in keyof T]`]: (...arg: string[]) => void;
  ...
}

const routeMapService: ProxedRouteMap<RouteMap> = new Proxy(routeMap, {
  apply(target, thisArg, ...args) {
    ...
  }
});
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wR95nW) meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer; if not, please explain any unsatisfied use cases.

Comment: @jcalz thank you, that is really very nice solution and probably should be added as answer too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `as` clause in [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) through which a transformation of the generated property names can be specified:

```
type ProxedRouteMap<T> = {
  [P in keyof T as `get${Capitalize<string & P>}Url`]: (...arg: string[]) => string;
} & {
  [P in keyof T as `goTo${Capitalize<string & P>}`]: (...arg: string[]) => void;
}

/**
 * {
 *  getRouteAUrl: (...arg: string[]) => string;
 *  getRouteBUrl: (...arg: string[]) => string;
 *  getRouteCUrl: (...arg: string[]) => string;
 * } & {
 *  goToRouteA: (...arg: string[]) => void;
 *  goToRouteB: (...arg: string[]) => void;
 *  goToRouteC: (...arg: string[]) => void;
 * } 
 */
type Foo = ProxedRouteMap<RouteMap>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoHsCukCycAOyA3gLABQyyUWkAggFzIDOYUoA5gNzmXXYQAhRizYguPKjQgBhYaw7cKyAPTLkAOk3kAvuXIJ0IFpP5M8+Rhn7nkAXmIS+dRgHInEALRwPmKABsXABpHKSFkNykPACMff2V6fDgoOABbIJD+WXD3DwRYv3imdBTPYAATZTK4MDh0pVUNLTJdMnIwAE98FAAFagAPCDKrXAIAHgAVAD47ByUAbW7kUGQAawh29BhkceQ4JmQAA3YIMAASImkCYBq-YAAvCFGRDmQAMmRuye0AVX8DgF1GAAKTTqJLsOSidhzf4ASjs02eYkU2jes0olAWSxAq3Wm22u32R3Q43Q50u+GucFuDye8jEaM+2gBwNB4MhHBh8Ns0wAbuhyopKC1yMoAFRinhi9HS5DHMDDCC0X5+VmadnMenQuEIzVQoWy+WKgQqtVgqAQvWcnU8q3IqWUI1SaSm5Ag9UWjliLm6pHiCjS1HvUgBx0k9CKhhutmeu3a7l8gVlA1h0nGs0av0+238wUOuXhxVZd3my1Zm2JvOh1FS5RtTooABi6HQM166AGQyk5lGivMkz0ZAMRjAJhG+AAytBecAkDMQBAAO4ffrtIHuMwEQLo3b4fB+Nc1C0nbdgAAWwCYtAt25j7CY8JDGJUalBEha2nhe12IHahJXHaDH2YzAfgkycEAA)

---

Or even simpler:

```
type ProxedRouteMap<T> = {
  [P in `get${Capitalize<keyof T & string>}Url`]: (...arg: string[]) => string;
} & {
    [P in `goTo${Capitalize<keyof T & string>}`]: (...arg: string[]) => void;
  }
```